# Yii2 ActiveRecord Model best practice

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have these classes:

**Model:**

```
namespace app\models;

use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class MyModel extends ActiveRecord {

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['name'], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'default', 'value' => null]
    ];
}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\MyModel;

class MymodelController extends Controller{

    public function actionEdit($id = null){
        $model = new MyModel();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('msg', 'Model has been saved with ID ' . $model->id);
        }

        return $this->render('edit', [
           'model' => $model 
        ]);
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('msg')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('msg'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'id');  ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I want to use this view for editing and for inserting. Editing does not work as it is, because I am creating a new object instead of changing an existing one in the Controller. I am unsure what is the best practice here or if I am missing some already existing built in function?

- Should I create my own model class and implement the logic model <-> active record in the controller

or

- Should I just re query the database with the `$model->id` in the controller and copy all properties if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CRUD (Create, Read/View, Update and delete) you can use gii. This power tool generate automatically all you need for an ActiveRecord, Controller with the basic action (index, view, create, update, delete, find) and related view.

In gii you first genearate model class and then generate CRUD for this class.

But the most informant things all this information are coerently related each other

see this doc is very useful and the best pratice for Yii2 is embetted in the tool 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

Comment: Haven't used Gii before but I just tried it and the created code is a great reference to learn more about Yii2.

Comment: Exactly is a very interesting source of information as well as a tool that greatly simplifies the creation of code. And even more interesting it is to see how it is done so you can learn many elements of the deep structure of the framework ..

Answer (score 3):

you should use two actions for edit and insertion

for edit first find the model

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('edit', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

 protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = MyModel::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
```

if you use CRUD for generating your controller you don't have to write these actions.

Comment: So the '$id' parameter is also set when I submit the form?

Comment: when you click on a button for edit you must also pass the $model->id

Answer (score 0):

In Your Create action:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Yourmodel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In your Update action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } 
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: So findModel is something I have to implement myself, correct?